# Having trouble format decimal point in Excel with JasperReport

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I made an excel report, which contains some `Double` type `TextFields` with number format pattern `##0.#`

In OpenOffice, these cells are formatted correctly (Which is exactly what I need)

- 1.56 -> 1.6
- 0.0 -> 0

However, when I opened report with Microsoft Excel, the decimal point did not disappear like I excpected.

- 1.56 -> 1.6
- 0.0 -> **0.**

After some search, I found a post about number format in Excel.

> [In Excel format number with optional decimal places](https://superuser.com/questions/205759/in-excel-format-number-with-optional-decimal-places)

I tried `[=0]0;.#` instead as the post suggested. But Excel complain about about my cell number format are broken.

My question is : What pattern should I use in JasperReport, so Excel won't show the trailing decimal point ?

**UPDATE** : I just find out the pattern described in link dose not solve all cases, it match only 0, not 1.0, 2.0... etc.

Comment: Did you find the correct format in Excel?

Comment: No, I can't even make number format I want in Excel, it seems Excel dose not support format like this ?

Comment: What Excel (version) are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula`*** property.

The sample:

```xml
<textField pattern="##0.#">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula" value="[=0]0;##0,#"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sum}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

In my case the comma (`,`) is delimiter in my OS.

The information about ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula`*** property you can find [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula).

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, I just noticed the pattern `[=0]0;##0.#` described in the my link dose not solve all cases, it only match 0, not 1.0, 2.0...etc

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you may paste in field this code:

```
new DecimalFormat("0.##").format($F{bigdecValue})
```

So, processing for xls will be without comma if thera are trailinig zeros.